# Existence of smooth partition of unity

Tags: calculus, manifolds

Suppose that $0<\alpha_1<\cdots<\alpha_n<1$. Let $M$ be a smooth paracompact connected manifold of dimension $d$.
Let $(U_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a locally finite open covering of $M$. Suppose that each $U_k$ is relatively compact.

Is it true that there exists a partition of unity $(\zeta_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $M$ subordinates to the open covering $(U_k)_k$ such that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $\zeta_k$ and $\zeta_k^{\alpha_1}$ and $\cdots$ $\zeta_k^{\alpha_n}$ are smooth?

I want to know especially the result when $\alpha_1=\frac{1}{4}, \alpha_2=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What does $f^{\alpha}$ mean? It's $f^\alpha(x)= (f(x))^{\alpha}$?

Comment: Yes it is. Yes it is.